# How to get the value in my form

Tags: php, mysql

Good Day

my main problem is how can I supply the value in the form to query.

this code gets the id from other table:

```
if (isset($_GET['machine_no_id']) && is_numeric($_GET['machine_no_id']))
 {
    $id = $_GET['machine_no_id'];
    echo $id;
 }
```

then this code only get the value in form:

```
 if (isset($_GET['submit']))
{
   $qty = $_GET['qty'];
   echo $qty;
}
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign name to your submit button like `<input type="submit" Value="Add" name="submit">`.

and in php part,

```
if(isset($_GET['submit'])){    
    //insert query    
}
```

and you will get the quantity value by `$_GET['add_qty']`

and its better if u use the `method = 'post'` and call the variables using `$_POST` instead of `$_GET`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add submit button in HTML form like,

```
<input type="submit" Value="Add" name="submit">
```

And set method to 'POST' in HTML form As it is better to use POST method instead of GET, In PHP code use `$_POST` to check whether form is submitted or not like,

```
if($_POST){
  // put your PHP code here
}
```

And Then you can get the quantity value by $_POST['add_qty'];

Comment: `<?php
 include('connect-db.php');
 
 if (isset($_GET['machine_no_id']) && is_numeric($_GET['machine_no_id']))
  {
  $id = $_GET['machine_no_id'];
  echo $id;
  }
 if (isset($_GET['submit']))
 {
    $qty = $_GET['qty'];
    echo $qty;
 }
 mysql_query("UPDATE master_tbl SET qty_left = qty_left + '$qty' WHERE machine_no_id='$id'"); 
?>`

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: qty in C:\xampp\htdocs\spacs\quick_add.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<input type="submit" Value="Add" name="submit">

if (isset($_GET['submit']))
{
   // get id value
   $id = $_GET['machine_no_id'];
   $qty = $_GET['add_qty'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <html>
   <body>
    <form action="" method="POST">
    <table border="1" cellpadding="5" align="center">
    <tr>
    <td>ID:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="id"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Quantity:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="add_qty"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" Value="Add"></td>
    </tr>
    /table>
    </form>
</body>
```

```
    <?php
     // connect to the database
     include('connect-db.php');

     // check if the 'id' variable is set in URL, and check that it is valid
     if (isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
     {
     // get id value
     $id = $_POST['id'];
     $qty = $_POST['add_qty'];

     echo $id;
     echo $qty;


    //mysql_query("UPDATE master_tbl SET qty_left = qty_left + '$qty' WHERE machine_no_id='$id'");

    //header("location: show_result.php");

    }
    ?>
```